# picture box does not showing last uploaded image when i rerun the application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, picturebox

hi i have  picturebox with displaying image when i click on button its fine...

but when i close the application and again i run the application it does not shows the last uploaded image  and this is my code ....

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.FileName = @"D:\";

        openFileDialog1.Filter = "png files (*.png)|*.png|jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";
        openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
        openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {


            Image image1 = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pictureBox1.Image = image1;
            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = image1;



        }

    }
}
```

i want show the the  last uploaded image in picture box when i rerun the application again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then you need to save the location and load it again when the application starts.

From the `Solution Explorer`, open the `Properties` window and open the `Settings` tab.  Create a string called LastImage.

From code, you can save it:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.LastImage = openFileDialog1.FileName;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

and read it back when you open:

```
string myImage = Properties.Settings.Default.LastImage;
if (File.Exists(myImage))
{
  pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(myImage);
  //etc...
}
```

Comment: oh okk but i am not able to find the properties.settings.lastimage it is showing properties.setttings.defualt like this..

Comment: sorry for this.. still i am not able to find this one ...Properties.Settings.Default.LastImage (.lastimage)..

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx  This article explains how to add properties/settings to your project. You can use them afterwards as LarsTech already explained nicely.

Comment: @user903550 You have to first open "Properties" in your "Solution Explorer" and select the "Settings" tab.  Create the string variable "LastImage" and save your solution.  It will then become available to you in code.